# Bot Framework send message to different user

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot that does a hand-off to a human operator.  
When the operator joins I receive an event in the 'OnEventActivityAsync' event. 
At that moment I want to send a message to the client that they're connected to the operator. 
How do I change the turnContext/Activity to send the message to the client?

Not entirely sure which part of code to post. (can't post entire project due to company policies)

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/agentJoin")
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("webchat/agentJoin");        
        //Database stuff here 
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Connected to customer"), cancellationToken);
        
        //How do I send a message to the client here? turnContext sends the message to the agent, not client

    }
}
```

Comment: please check the following handoff solution link.https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with that project, but it uses a completely different architecture. 
Is there no easy way to say 'I want to send this activity to user xx' ?

Comment: Are you still utilising an architecture where the customer AND agent are different conversations? (where bot framework acts as a proxy). Have you tried sending the message as proactive message to the customer? You would need to retrieve their address from the database.

Comment: Hi Mick, yeah, we're still using that architecture. I did try proactive messages a while ago, but didn't get it to work because of 'unauthorized' error. 
I looked at it again today, and fixed it. (Apparently I missed that fix in the documentation when I first looked ;) )
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors

Answer (score 0):

Please See protocol definition in the below GitHub link experimentations:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/handoff-library

Factory Methods

SDK will include the following factory method to aid in creation of the events specified:

C#:

```
namespace Microsoft.Bot.Builder 

{ 

    public static class EventFactory 

    { 

        public static IEventActivity CreateHandoffInitiation( 

            ITurnContext turnContext, 

            object handoffContext, 

            Transcript transcript); 

 

        public static IEventActivity CreateHandoffResponse( 

            ConversationAccount Conversation, 

            string code); 

 

        public static IEventActivity CreateHandoffCompleted( 

            ConversationAccount Conversation, 

            string code, 

            Transcript transcript); 

    } 

}
```

Protocol codes are defined as follows:

```
namespace Microsoft.Bot.Schema 

{ 

    public static class HandoffCodes 

    { 

        public const string Accepted = "accepted"; 

        public const string Failed = "failed"; 

        public const string TimedOut = "timedOut"; 

        public const string EndOfConversation = "endOfConversation"; 

        public const string TransferBack = "transferBack"; 

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion by Mick I took another look at proactive messages.
I had looked at it before, but never got it to work because of 'Unauthorized' errors.
Now I noticed there's a fix for that specific problem.

The code is based on the MS documentation for sending proactive notifications:
[Send proactive Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

So what I do is:

```
turnContext.Adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));

private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // If you encounter permission-related errors when sending this message, see
    // https://aka.ms/BotTrustServiceUrl
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("You're now connected to: Ted");
}
```